# How create a rule in CRON to complete the process by name deamon?

Tags: linux, cron

I want that cron kill deamon by name at 7am and starts this deamon at 8am which lies in another directory. Please help me!)

Comment: "write teh code, pretty plz!"

Comment: I do not know much Linux , especially how work CRON